# Copying text from one file to another using Javascript

Tags: copy, jscript, fso

I wrote a script (.js) which should copy all text from one file to another, but it doesn't work (i run it on hard disc):

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var myInputTextStream = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\FILE\\back_log.log", 1, true);
var log = "C:\\Temp\\26_04_2012_16_22_49\\ext.txt";     
    var myOutputTextStream = fso.OpenTextFile(log, 8, true);
    while(myInputTextStream.AtEndOfStream)
        {
      myOutputTextStream.Write(myInputTextStream.ReadAll());
    }
      //myInputTextStream.Close();
      //myOutputTextStream.Close(); 
    WScript.Echo("FINISH!!!");
```

Could anybody coorrect me (or code=))? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is something that should normally be handled server side.

Comment: Why not simply use a batch one-liner for this? `copy C:\Temp\26_04_2012_16_22_49\ext.txt+C:\FILE\back_log.log C:\Temp\26_04_2012_16_22_49\ext.txt` or `type C:\FILE\back_log.log >> C:\Temp\26_04_2012_16_22_49\ext.txt`

Comment: @Event_Horizon: The OP means JScript used in Windows Script Host (similar to VBScript, PowerShell or batch files), not JavaScript in browsers.

Comment: Interesting, did not know you could do batch file stuff with js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myInputTextStream.AtEndOfStream` is `false` until reading reaches the `EOF`. Hence your `while`-loop is never executed.

If you use `ReadAll()`, you don't need the `while`-loop at all.

You should also never comment out your `Close()`-methods, you may get troubles, especially when using portable memory devices like SDI-cards etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a file like this:

```
var fso, f;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\testfile.txt", true);
f.WriteLine("This is a test.");
f.Close();
f = fso.GetFile("c:\\testfile.txt");
f.Copy("c:\\windows\\desktop\\test2.txt");
```

(This creates a file and then copies it, so just use the useful part, which is contained in the last 2 lines.)

Excerpt taken from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6973t06a%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

since javascript cannot access the local "C" drive, not sure where you would use this.  SInce you will be running this locally on your machine, why not just use a dos command, vbscript or wscript?  javascript is overkill.